# Charting Control for Windows 7 CE with Silverlight 3

Tags: silverlight, windows-embedded-compact, windows-7-embedded

I have to implement charting controls(waveforms specifically) that can be n in number and have to plot them dynamically with certain range of values.

I am using Silverlight 3 for Windows Embedded and i have to code for an embedded device.

Windows Embedded 7 uses VC++ code but there are no charting controls.

I think I will be needing to write a control for that.

I am novoice. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15856553/1553481).