# Charting control options for Silverlight for Windows Embedded

Tags: silverlight-3.0, windows-embedded-compact

I want to make a charting control for an embedded device using Silverlight for Windows Embedded. Currently i am planning to use line shape for drawing the graph.

My question is if its a good approach(performance wise) or should i look for other options.
Or if any controls are available for SWE.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight is not a proper answer to drawing charts on an Windows Embedded Compact device. You should go for using (or creating) a native GDI element. If performance is very important (e.g. for a fast-updating chart), you might also consider DirectDraw.

The **best way** in a commercial project would probably be to use a readymade component, such as [this one](http://www.resco.net/mobileformstoolkit/details.aspx?comp=CompactChart&p=WindowsMobile).

You can find somebody else's experiences and advice [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winembnatapp/thread/d070f6f5-6cfc-4c83-9644-be856b000956) for pointers to what to look for when doing this yourself. If you expand your post with more details about what you are actually trying to achieve, I might give you a more detailed response.

Comment: I am trying to make charting control for a data logger used for observing real-time data, and yes performance is important.So if i host GDI control for plotting the waveforms in my silverlight(only for overlays) application will it be efficient??

Comment: @H3llrais3R Much more so that if you use Silverlight. Also, SWE is a royal pain in the ... to deal with. Do you plan to do an oscilloscope-type thing? And what's your actual hardware platform?

Comment: ya its similar to oscilloscope, using an i.MX53 for hardware.

Comment: If you plan to have 'real-time' (like in 30fps) updates, I'd sure go for DirectDraw. You can fine-tune GDI code to squeeze more performance out of it as it is a relatively powerful processor in comparison to what I saw being developed for in Windows CE, but you'd still be having a hard time to make this work smoothly in GDI. DirectDraw is the most efficient graphics subsystem on Windows Embedded.

Comment: thanks for giving a direction. Will award the bounty tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

The answer is stop using Silverlight, since Microsoft is abandoning the product. Do it in Flash—or better yet, use HTML5 and JavaScript.

Comment: It is bad advice to suggest using web technologies in an application on an embedded Windows device.

Answer (score 0):

In recent windows embedded applications that use windows universal apps I would highly recommend oxyplot.

http://oxyplot.org/

These plots are the best I've found on the internet so far and very easy to use. Best of all they are free. You can get these using a NuGet Package manager which makes getting updates fairly simple.